# Embedding a dynamic website into Sharepoint online

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have created a dynamic website using a framework, which exports an `index.html` and several folders like `assets`, `libraries` etc.

According to `Sharepoint`'s description (which we have through `Office365`), I have to rename the `index.html` to `index.aspx`, then follow the steps:
A full description of what I did, would be as follows:

1. Open **Site Contents**
2. Select **Add an app**
3. Select **Document Library**
4. Name the library
5. Click **Create**
6. Open the library in a web browser
7. Upload the HTML files to this library

To display the HTML content on a SharePoint page:

1. Open **Site Contents**
2. Open the **Site Pages library**
3. From the ribbon select **Files > New Document > Wiki page**
4. Give the page a name then click **Create**
5. In the SharePoint page editor select **Insert** from the ribbon then **Web Part** then **Media** and **Content** category then **Content Editor** and **Add**
6. Click on the **Script Editor** box, then select **Web Part** then **Web Part Properties** from the ribbon
7. In the Content Link box click the elipsis (...) and find the HTML/ASPX file to display or paste in the full URL to the HTML/ASPX file
8. Click **OK** to close the web page dialog
9. Click **Save** to save the page
   The contents of the HTML/ASPX file is now displayed on the SharePoint page.

The following options are enabled:

```
Run custom script on personal sites

Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites
```

The problem is, that most of the `elements` on the `index.aspx` page like `video`, `interactive pictures`, `buttons` just reload the page and show in the developer tool of the browser `error 403`.

Is there any right way of implementing a `dynamic web page` into `Sharepoint`?